# How can I use words/letters as pixels in an image?

Tags: graphics, string-manipulation

I'd like to take the text of a novel or whatever and arrange it in a way that forms an image.  Essentially recreating these works from Postertext. [image: whale]
<sub>(source: [litstack.com](http://www.litstack.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/whale.png))</sub>  .

[image]

I'm mostly looking for ideas regarding a promising plan of attack for this problem, not necessarily full solutions.  Of course, code for smaller pieces of the puzzle are welcome.

`ExampleData[{"Text","AliceInWonderland"}]` is useful for testing solutions.

Comment: The biggest challenge here to getting this right is I think hyphenating the words ( almost certainly required for it to look good ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a crude attempt, just using a monospace  font and arbitrarily breaking the words..

```
i = 0;
alice = ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}];
i0 = Binarize@ImageResize[ ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}] , {100}];
r = {ImageCrop[
      Rasterize[
       Style[StringJoin@#, FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Courier", 
        FontWeight -> "Bold"], RasterSize -> {800, 30}, 
       ImageSize -> {800, 30}], {800, 7}]} & /@ 
   Map[ If[# == 0, StringTake[alice, {++i}] , " " ] & , 
    ImageData@i0 , {2} ] ;
Row[ {Show[i0, ImageSize -> 260], 
   Show[ImageAssemble[r], ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

```
 ImageTake[ ImageAssemble[r] , {1, 100}, {1, 300}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When I read your title, I thought "I know how to use letters as pixels of an image..." and answered. But then I re-read your question and realized that it was different altogether. Maybe some part of this will be useful...

One approach is to rasterize all the letters, then scan through the picture and find out which letter is closest to the image at each point. Start by generating a collection of rasterized letters (for simplicity later on, make them all the same size).

```
allChar = Characters[
 "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+1234567890-=;:'\"/?.>,<~`|\\\\ "]; 
allLetsUnequal = 
 Rasterize[
    Style[#, FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Courier", 
     FontWeight -> "Bold"], RasterSize -> 20] & /@ allChar;
allSizes = ImageDimensions[#] & /@ allLetsUnequal;
maxSize = {Max[allSizes[[All, 1]]], Max[allSizes[[All, 2]]]};
allLetsPos = 
 ImageAdd[Image[ConstantArray[0, RotateRight@maxSize]], #] & /@ 
  allLetsUnequal; allLetsNeg = ColorNegate[#] & /@ allLetsPos;
allLets = Flatten[{allLetsPos, allLetsNeg}];
```

Now grab an image and partition it. Use a Nearest function to find the best letter for each partition.

[image]

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVXtV.png"];
img2 = ImageResize[img, 900];
imgParts = ImagePartition[img2, maxSize];
dims = Dimensions[imgParts];
nf = Nearest[allLets];
asciiLets = 
  Table[First@nf[imgParts[[i, j]]], {i, 1, First@dims}, {j, 1, 
      Last@dims}]; 
ImageAssemble[asciiLets]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this meets the OP's requirements. The images shown in the question are clearly posterized down to two levels, full black and full white with the black pixels being replaced with lines of vectorized text drawn at a very small font size to get a fairly uniform gray. The text, when the image is sufficiently enlarged, reads line for line as it the original. The kind of ascii art you generate operates on very different principles.